# Activity overview not displaying today's reputation correctly

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, user-interface

The user activity overview dialog that you see when you mouse over your user name at the top of the page normally displays the reputation that you gained on the current day.  This was handy for telling if you were close to the reputation cap.

I just noticed that the dialog is now displaying the combined reputation that I gained yesterday and today (3.5 hours into a new day).

[image: Activity Overview]

Was this an intentional change to display the reputation gained in the last 24 hours, or is this a display/caching bug?

Comment: I also have same issue.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

We run a job once a day to reset these totals to `0` for everyone *exactly* at UTC midnight, unfortunately when deploying network-wide changes to fix associations permanently some servers went *absolutely batshit crazy* due to a few race conditions.  Our status dashboard looked like a Christmas tree for the better part of a hour.  Hopefully though, you saw very few errors during this.

The reputation dropdown is driven off of 5 columns in the database from your user record: `Reputation`, `ReputationWeek`, `ReputationMonth`, `ReputationQuarter` and `ReputationYear`.  The way we maintain these is incredibly simple, a trigger.  When `Reputation` changes, that same delta is applied to all the other columns.  When the interval rolls over, the job running at UTC midnight resets whatever intervals are changing to 0 for everyone in a simple update.

Due to the server farm **FREAKING THE HELL OUT**, that didn't happen.  Honestly, it's just not worth fixing IMO, since it only affects the day interval and will fix itself tonight in the rollover.

If it's that important to people we *can* fix the totals for today, but unless there's a large cry to do so, I'll spend time on bigger fish today (e.g. showing actual rep change from when a user is deleted in a sensible way, or post migrations as "migrated" instead of "removed" in the rep history).

Comment: Middle year Christmas - isn't this wonderful? :) Anyway - can we tell (in a comment) to all those reporting here today about this issue that it will resolve itself by tomorrow?

Comment: Nah, I wouldn't worry about it if it's going to right itself at midnight UTC.  Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Yes, stick to the big fish

Comment: @ShaDowWizArd - absolutely, if it comes up close as a duplicate of this.

Comment: Well, about 5 I counted and I think there are more that get deleted quicker than I can notice. But still, I agree it can wait. Thanks!

Comment: Ah ha, was that why things seemed to get sluggish for a bit last night?

Comment: @Tim - Yup, some `Init()` code on StackAuth/API v1 was running many, many *many* times due the timeout/retry mechanism in the pipeline - producing some very bad side-effects.  Once we sorted out that memory gobbling (literally *all* of it) problem, everything settled down.

Comment: Ouch, that sounds pretty nasty. Credit to the team though - all I noticed was the brief period of slow response times, so seems things held together pretty well under the circumstances.

Comment: _"post migrations as 'migrated' instead of 'removed'"_; yes please! Does this mean that it may come sooner than you [previously indicated](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123319/recent-reputation-history-changes/124198#124198)?

Comment: @Ben - Yup, it's in place now.  Anything migrated to another site and deleted will now show as "migrated" in your rep history.

Comment: Looks like it happened again last night; more Christmas lights at midnight?

Comment: @MartijnPieters - yep, the scheduler service ate it about 12 hours ago, we're looking into what happened