# Difference between actual reputation and what's shown on the top

Tags: bug, reputation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Activity overview not displaying today's reputation correctly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125694/activity-overview-not-displaying-todays-reputation-correctly)

Today I have noticed a discrepancy between my actual reputation for the day and the one shown on the top:

[image]

and the actual reputation:

[image]

It's as if the counter hasn't been reset this night. Am I missing something? Caching issue?