# Why is the popup summary window showing the wrong reputation for today?

Tags: bug, reputation, popups

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Activity overview not displaying today's reputation correctly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125694/activity-overview-not-displaying-todays-reputation-correctly)

It should be obvious from the screenshot. The value of 70 is the correct value.

[image]

Comment: @Cody Who are the others? And I don't feel too bad about this being a dupe because multiple reproductions can be valuable to those hunting bugs.

Comment: Originally, Bill the Lizard. Then Jon Skeet opened a bug report and deleted it before it reached 4 close votes. Darin [has one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125713/difference-between-actual-reputation-and-whats-shown-on-the-top) currently active, and now you.

Comment: @Cody Darin's report is cool. Even for him, 715 in a day would be going some!

Comment: @CodyGray I am not a top user, and I noticed this too. (But I canceled my question because I found Bills.)

Comment: *multiple reproductions can be valuable to those hunting bugs* - not if you don't give any new information (which you don't) and even so - you can add the new information as comment or answer in the first existing bug report.

Comment: @ShaDowWizArd Well I'm very sorry about that. Perhaps I should not bother attempting to help in future.

Comment: @David that's not what I meant. What I mean is that if you see existing bug report about the same issue there's no need to post your own as new report. If you didn't spot such existing report of course you better rush in and report. I just disagree about your first comment here that's all.

Comment: @ShaDowWizArd You are assuming something about the bug. Perhaps it's only easy to debug for certain users. I can't believe that's the case here, but those with debugging powers can determine that.

Comment: egads.  dem glasses