# Did something change recently in the treatment of dates?

Tags: support, dates

I just noticed that my reputation from UTC-yesterday (243) is still showing up combined with UTC-today's reputation (10), which has never happened before. Is this a new feature? Does this mean I can actually hit the rep cap in the leisure of my own time zone?

[image: "Today" inconsistencies]

Apparently it doesn't count towards votes, however, as I had exhausted my votes for UTC-yesterday and I can now vote once more. Same goes for revisions and favorites, as you can see in the screenshot.

Comment: To re-rail this: No, it's not a new feature. I've seen it a couple of times, something wasn't reset at midnight. Days still are UTC.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Yeah, me as well. But at that time I wasn't sure about UTC, thought it could be local time or sumfink.

Comment: I checked the release notes faq and it wasn't mentioned. Also it doesn't look that way on the rep tab in the profile so its probably something funky with the drop down

Comment: Reproduced here: 248 in a popup, while the actual value is 55

Comment: possible duplicate of [Activity overview not displaying today's reputation correctly](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125694/activity-overview-not-displaying-todays-reputation-correctly)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about the older-style dropdown that was removed back in 2013 when the top bar was redesigned.