# Reputation Drop-Down Counter Broken

Tags: bug

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Daily reputation score on SO did not reset to zero at midnight UTC on 2012-06-06](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134782/daily-reputation-score-on-so-did-not-reset-to-zero-at-midnight-utc-on-2012-06-06)

When I click the little arrow next to my name on SO, I was happy to see that my reputation for Today is 325.  Except that it is not.

If I click on "325", it takes me to my reputation summary, showing that it is in fact 210 (as of this writing).

Yesterday's reputation gain was 115, so apparently the 325 labeled Today is really Today + Yesterday.

Comment: That occasionally happens. Sometimes the counter is not reset at midnight UTC. Was reported earlier today as http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134677/did-something-change-recently-in-the-treatment-of-dates