# Are tag statistics frozen?

Tags: bug

Yesterday morning I was looking at my tag statistics and I distinctly remember seeing at least these two:

```
863 - Java
92 - C
```

During the rest of yesterday I've answered a bunch of questions on both Java and C and got upvotes for them (I was actually expecting the bronze for C today) and looking now I see exactly the same numbers as yesterday (and I'm absolutely sure an entire day has gone by, because the reputation tab lists 15 points for today).

I thought these statistics are updated after each day (at least it was like this before). Is something wrong?

Comment: They're cached. Exactly how long, I don't know, but I _think_ more than a day.

Comment: @Tim ManishEarth: Are you sure? I've never seen this behavior before.

Comment: Nope. Also, check if its a UTC day. IMO, you should wait an extra day before reporting the bug. Anyway, it's sort of valid, don't delete it now :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Activity overview not displaying today's reputation correctly](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125694/activity-overview-not-displaying-todays-reputation-correctly)

Comment: Noticed the same thing, concurrent with the weird rep overflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, the stats in the user activity dialog are calculated based on a database table that *usually* gets reset every UTC midnight, by means of a automated job.

It looks like the job didn't run again last night. This happened before and is nothing to worry about, see [Activity overview not displaying today's reputation correctly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125694/activity-overview-not-displaying-todays-reputation-correctly)

If the job itself isn't botched it should run again tonight and your stats will auto-correct.

Comment: This is the correct answer - a job wasn't correctly run, but has successfully completed now.