# Daily reputation score on SO did not reset to zero at midnight UTC on 2012-06-06

Tags: bug, status-completed

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Activity overview not displaying today's reputation correctly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125694/activity-overview-not-displaying-todays-reputation-correctly)
>   [Did something change recently in the treatment of dates?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134677/did-something-change-recently-in-the-treatment-of-dates)

The drop down status summary on SO for me shows I have 365 points today.  I wish!  It did not reset to zero when midnight UTC rolled around.

Is there a glitch in the system?  Is it only me that's affected?

Comment: It is not only you that is affected, as I am, too.

Comment: Thanks for the reassurance, @Phrogz.

Comment: I am having the [same issue](http://i.stack.imgur.com/hEGbq.png)

Comment: Me too. I also noted in a question I posted earlier that the tag statistics seem to be frozen: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134730/are-tag-statistics-frozen

Comment: I was affected on DBA StackExchange in a similar way. The number of votes on some of my tags did not update in SO and DBA.SE.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Our task scheduler took a dive last night so this reset task didn't run...new code is being deployed later today so this particular crash doesn't happen again.

As noted before, we won't be fixing this since it wasn't more than a day interval (e.g. wasn't a week, month, year reset) and will fix itself tomorrow...it's just not worth the time investment/opportunity cost.

Comment: FWIW: the numbers were reset at midnight UTC 2012-06-07.

Answer (score 5):

It looks like this is a known glitch that occurs occasionally.  The best explanation seems to be:

- [Activity overview not displaying today's reputation correctly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125694/activity-overview-not-displaying-todays-reputation-correctly)

A quick summary is:

> - There's a process that should be triggered at midnight UTC to reset the daily score to zero.
> - Sometimes, it misses and scores accumulate over an extra day.
> - It is reset at the next midnight UTC.
> - The SO/SE team don't plan to fix it during the day.