# Wrong Reputation in the QuickView Pane

Tags: bug, reputation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Daily reputation score on SO did not reset to zero at midnight UTC on 2012-06-06](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134782/daily-reputation-score-on-so-did-not-reset-to-zero-at-midnight-utc-on-2012-06-06)

I guess this is a bug. Did not see a bugtracker /feedback link in any SO sites. So posting it here.

In the Quick View pane (Is that the name ?) in home page, It shows **230** as my todays reputation ( which is wrong) and when i clicked on it, it shows me the correct statistics. Here are the screenshots.

[image]

And Yes. I did an Audit by visiting https://stackoverflow.com/reputation many times !. No change !

Who forgot to checkin the code ? :)

Comment: (and/or [Activity overview not displaying today's reputation correctly](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125694))